# How to set Scroll view in my layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am created a DashbordLayout to view list of button. I need to set scroll viewer in my layout. My layout is shown here:

```
<com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal.DashboardLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#f8f9fe">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_news_feed"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/place"
    android:text="@string/my_place" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_friends"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/education"
    android:text="@string/education" />

<!--  Messages Button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_messages"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/bus"
    android:text="@string/bus_time" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_places"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/train"
    android:text="@string/train_time" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_events"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/auto"
    android:text="@string/auto" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_photos"
   style="@style/DashboardButton"
   android:drawableTop="@drawable/taxi"
   android:text="@string/taxi" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_goods"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/goods"
    android:text="@string/goods" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_business"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/business"
    android:text="@string/business" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_hospital"
   style="@style/DashboardButton"
   android:drawableTop="@drawable/hospital"
   android:text="@string/hospital" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_bleed"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/blood"
    android:text="@string/bleed_bank" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_pani"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/pani"
    android:text="@string/pani" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_emergency"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/emergency"
    android:text="@string/emergency" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_feedback"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/feedback"
    android:text="@string/feedback" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_we"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/we"
    android:text="@string/we" />
```

[image]

This layout is created with following class is given bellow.

```
 package com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal;


 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class DashboardLayout extends ViewGroup {

private static final int UNEVEN_GRID_PENALTY_MULTIPLIER = 10;

private int mMaxChildWidth = 0;
private int mMaxChildHeight = 0;

public DashboardLayout(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public DashboardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, 0);
}

public DashboardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    mMaxChildWidth = 0;
    mMaxChildHeight = 0;

    // Measure once to find the maximum child size.

    int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);

        mMaxChildWidth = Math.max(mMaxChildWidth, child.getMeasuredWidth());
        mMaxChildHeight = Math.max(mMaxChildHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight());
    }



    childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            mMaxChildWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            mMaxChildHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(
            resolveSize(mMaxChildWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
            resolveSize(mMaxChildHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int width = r - l;
    int height = b - t;

    final int count = getChildCount();

    // Calculate the number of visible children.
    int visibleCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }
        ++visibleCount;
    }

    if (visibleCount == 0) {
        return;
    }


    int bestSpaceDifference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int spaceDifference;

    // Horizontal and vertical space between items
    int hSpace = 0;
    int vSpace = 0;

    int cols = 1;
    int rows;

    while (true) {
        rows = (visibleCount - 1) / cols + 1;

        hSpace = ((width - mMaxChildWidth * cols) / (cols + 1));
        vSpace = ((height - mMaxChildHeight * rows) / (rows + 1));

        spaceDifference = Math.abs(vSpace - hSpace);
        if (rows * cols != visibleCount) {
            spaceDifference *= UNEVEN_GRID_PENALTY_MULTIPLIER;
        }

        if (spaceDifference < bestSpaceDifference) {
            // Found a better whitespace squareness/ratio
            bestSpaceDifference = spaceDifference;


            if (rows == 1) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            // This is a worse whitespace ratio, use the previous value of cols and exit.
            --cols;
            rows = (visibleCount - 1) / cols + 1;
            hSpace = ((width - mMaxChildWidth * cols) / (cols + 1));
            vSpace = ((height - mMaxChildHeight * rows) / (rows + 1));
            break;
        }

        ++cols;
    }


    hSpace = Math.max(0, hSpace);
    vSpace = Math.max(0, vSpace);

    // Re-use width/height variables to be child width/height.
    width = (width - hSpace * (cols + 1)) / cols;
    height = (height - vSpace * (rows + 1)) / rows;

    int left, top;
    int col, row;
    int visibleIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
            continue;
        }

        row = visibleIndex / cols;
        col = visibleIndex % cols;

        left = hSpace * (col + 1) + width * col;
        top = vSpace * (row + 1) + height * row;

        child.layout(left, top,
                (hSpace == 0 && col == cols - 1) ? r : (left + width),
                (vSpace == 0 && row == rows - 1) ? b : (top + height));
        ++visibleIndex;
    }
   }
  }
```

I am gives a Scrollviewer in the begin of layout.But the layout alignment changes like below image

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
             ------- here DashbordLayout ------
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

I need to know how set scroll viewer in my alignment.

Comment: Try removing android:layout_weight="1" from com.psybo.shahi.localareaportal.DashboardLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```